# "RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL" error

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I'm trying to configure `.htaccess` of my website. 
http://213.175.210.49/~incisozl/ is the temporary url to the root(`~/public_html/`).

when I try to rewrite the url at `.htaccess` i get an

> `/home/incisozl/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL, referer: ht tp://213.175.210.49/~incisozl/inci-sozluk/somestring`

error.

my rewrite rule is;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=word&q=$1&sayfa=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk/([^\.\?/]+)?$ /seo.php?process=word&q=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=word&q=$1&sayfa=$2&gid=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluktest/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=wordtest&q=$1&sayfa=$2&gid=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-bugun/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=wordbg&q=$1&sayfa=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-bugun/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=wordbg&q=$1&sayfa=$2&gid=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-dun/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=worddn&q=$1&sayfa=$2&gid=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-dun/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=worddn&q=$1&sayfa=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-ters/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=wordts&q=$1&sayfa=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-ters/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=wordts&q=$1&sayfa=$2&gid=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-cvpters/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=cvpwordts&q=$1&sayfa=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-cvpters/([^\.\?/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=cvpwordts&q=$1&sayfa=$2&gid=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-ileti/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=eid&eid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^inci-sozluk-ileticvp/([0-9]+)/?$ /seo.php?process=cvpeid&eid=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

btw. it works fine when i use it with `www.incisozluk.org` pointed domain

Comment: cat /var/log/apache2/error.log will probably give you the solution, the correct path.

Comment: Well, does /~incisozl/ work? You'll have to switch between the two for local/remote use.

Comment: `referer: ht tp://213.175.210.49` - is the space in the http portion there in the original message as well? Is there some configuration typo or some such that's resulting in the base URL somehow getting that space inserted?

Answer (score 1):

That's strange since the only place where this error message is generated is in 
cmd_rewritebase() in modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c and the code is

```
if (a1[0] != '/') {
  return "RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL";
}
```

It tests whether the first character of the new value for RewriteBase is a /.
According to the code you've posted that is the case. Could there be another .htaccess file that has an invalid value?

Answer (score 1):

This is archaically old, but I just ran into this and for me the issue was having a slash on both the RewriteBase line and the RewriteRule line's destination.  I took the slash off the destination and the error went away!